# Returning an object.keys and comparing it to a function argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements

I'm having problems with the code below, but I can't figure out why my tests are not passing..

For example if I pass `canIGet('MacBook Air', 100);` this must return `false`, but instead is returning `true`

```
var canIGet = function(item, money) {
  itemPrices = {
   'MacBook Air': 999,
   'MacBook Pro': 1299,
   'Mac Pro': 2499,
   'Apple Sticker': 1  
  }

  if (itemPrices["MacBook Air"] >= money) {
    console.log(itemPrices["MacBook Air"], item, money);
    return true;
  } else if (itemPrices["MacBook Pro"] >= money)  {
    return true;
  } else if (itemPrices["Mac Pro"] >= money) {
    return true;
  } else if (itemPrices["Apple Sticker"] >= money) {
    return true;
  }  else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

My question is, should I be doing something like:

```
...
if (itemPrices.MacBookAir == item && itemPrices["MacBook Air"] >= money) {} ...
```

I want to compare that the item pass is the same as the key inside the `itemPrices`' object.

[JsBin link](https://jsbin.com/ruyibu/30/edit?js,console,output); the last function is at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statements, you are comparing against each key in `itemPrices` manually. There's no need to do that - you are already passing the correct key into the function as a variable (`item`). You can just use that variable to get the correct key in the object: `itemPrices[item]`. Now you know the price of the item that the user is asking for. Then you just compare that against the `price` variable.

So you can get rid of all of those if statements and replace it all with:

`return itemPrices[item] <= money;`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to see if you can afford one of the products in the `itemPrices` object, then perhaps you should just be doing this:

```
function canIGet(item, money) {
  itemPrices = {
   'MacBook Air': 999,
   'MacBook Pro': 1299,
   'Mac Pro': 2499,
   'Apple Sticker': 1  
  }
  // if we match an item in the prices object and the passed in 
  // money value is greater or equal to the price, then return true
  // otherwise return false
  return itemPrices[item] && money >= itemPrices[item];
}
```

The logic as you have it in your current function is somewhat backwards and the reason that `canIGet('MacBook Air', 100)` returns true is that your very first `if` statement is true and thus your function returns true.

That very first `if` statement is essentially this:

```
if (itemPrices["MacBook Air"] >= 100) {
```

which is `true` so your function then returns `true` which seems to be backward logic.  But, there's no reason to check all the items anyway.  Presumably you just want to check the item that was passed in which you can do as above using `itemPrices[item]`.

Comment: I suppose checking if the item exists in the array could be more readable, but it's not really necessary - if the item doesn't exist, the result will be undefined, and comparing undefined to any number will always result in `false`.

Comment: @MatisLepik - I prefer to never use `undefined` in a numeric comparison.  I don't like mixing types because it requires you to know a fair amount of minutiae about how JS does type conversions and that's a chance for less skilled developers to goof up.  That's just me making sure there's never a chance for an unknown type coercion to do something unexpected or for someone else to not quite understand how the code works or for someone else to modify the code and unexpectedly make a mistake.  So, I will sometimes use extra code to guard against that.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like;

```js
var itemPrices = {
                    'MacBook Air': 999,
                    'MacBook Pro': 1299,
                        'Mac Pro': 2499,
                  'Apple Sticker': 1  
                 },
       canIGet = (o,p,v) => o[p] <= v;

console.log(canIGet(itemPrices,'MacBook Air',100));
```